# How to add column in table based on left join using dax

Tags: dax

Add column in Table items based on left join on item_category table. I want to add column itemcategory_category in the items table based on the left join

```
=ADDCOLUMNS (
        items, LOOKUPVALUE (
        'item_category'[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY],
        'items'[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY], item_category[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]
        )
)
```

Items Table

```
KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY
    1
```

item_category table

```
KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY     ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY   
    1                            A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one to one relationship

```
Table = ADDCOLUMNS(items,"new",RELATED(item_category[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY]))
```

If you have no relationship

```
Table 2 = ADDCOLUMNS(items,"new",CALCULATE(MAXX(filter(item_category,item_category[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]=MAX(items[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY])),item_category[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY])))
```

If you are only keen on `LOOKUPVALUE` with or without relationship. `LOOKUPVALUE` is not dependent upon any relationship but it has performance issues.

```
Table 3 = ADDCOLUMNS(items,"new",LOOKUPVALUE(item_category[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY],item_category[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY],items[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]))
```

I tested out with following and it works fine.
[image: t1]

[image: t2]

[image: t3]

Comment: I need to discuss the second solution, Why you have used the max function

Comment: the solution is not working it shows
Calculated column 'items'[Calculated Column 1] : The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

Comment: so we are creating another table in the solution. I just need to append the column in the existing items table

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a calculated column in existing `item` table where as `ADDCOLUMNS` returns a table. If you want to do just that , use this  `CALCULATE(MAXX(filter(item_category,item_category[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]=MAX(items[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY])),item_category[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY]))` in `item`

Comment: Why we are using the MAXX function in this

Comment: Because you want to take the `max` of `items[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]))` available in the current row context (=1 for the first row, =2 for the second row in item) and pass on that value to a table expression which has an iterator as the table expression; [The table containing the rows for which the expression will be evaluated]. `MAXX(<Table>,<Expression>)`. The first argument `<Table>` in `MAXX` is an iterator; in our case it is filtered table which iterates based on `MAX(items[KEY_PRODUCTCATEGORY]))` to return `item_category[ITEMCATEGORY_CATEGORY])`